# Find the largest line numbers and implement the formula

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have output tables from php. I have the highest numbers with class topCislo. And every two lines of the result implement the highest numbers in the formula. All this until the full page is loaded.

Output table:

```html
                <table class="tabulka">
                  <tr class="timy">
                    <td class="box">
                      <div class="name"><a href="#" class="a-reset"><img alt="Barca" src="#" class="logo" title="Barca">Barca </a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">1.08</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">1.12</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">1.07</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="topCislo">8.50</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="growcell"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="timy">
                    <td class="box">
                      <div class="name"><a href="#" class="a-reset"><img alt="rTE" src="#" class="logo" title="rTE">rTE </a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">5.25</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">6.44</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">6.67</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">6.67</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="topCislo">8.50</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">6.00</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#">4.96</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="growcell"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="tabulka">
                  <tr class="timy">
                    <td class="box">
                      <div class="name"><a href="#" class="a-reset"><img alt="Sami" src="#" class="logo" title="Sami">Sami </a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="topCislo">7.76</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="growcell"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="timy">
                    <td class="box">
                      <div class="name"><a href="#" class="a-reset"><img alt="eSuba" src="#" class="logo" title="eSuba">eSuba </a></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="slabeCislo">1.05</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"><a href="#" class="topCislo">1.33</a></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="cislo"></td>
                    <td class="growcell"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

For every two rows 1 formula (2 rows = 1 table). For every table I need result from formula, the result from the formula will only be displayed, nothing will be done anymore.

Class topCislo (the highest number in row) is in href.

Formula:
`((((topCislo1 / (topCislo1 + topCislo2)) * topCislo2) + ((topCislo2 / (topCislo2 + topCislo1)) * topCislo1)) / 2)`

Please help me?

Comment: What is the specific problem and question? What you have written is confusing

Comment: I don't see any code, so we can't help you.  By `Please help me?` do you really mean `Please do it for me`?